# How to bundle exe file inside another exe file using nsis script

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, nsis

I have a installer file called sample.exe. This exe file will have some components that use have to be defined such as port number, installation directory and etc. I have to bundle this sample.exe file inside another installer called test.exe. So when i try to install the test.exe, it should also install the sample.exe. i could see there are options to achieve this in nsis, but how to provide options for the use to enter the port, directory path of sample.exe while installing the test.exe ? i am beginner to nsis and any reference are example script will help me lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **create custom** (installer) **page** where these values are entered.

Use nsDialogs for this (recommended): http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html

There is no exact solution for this as your specification is really vague, rather check the examples and use provided code snippets from them.

Answer (score 0):

You generally use the directory page to let the user choose the installation directory. Non-standard user input can be recorded on a custom page using the [nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) plug-in:

```
Name "Foo"
OutFile "TestSetup.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel admin
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\Test"
!define DEFAULTPORT 666

!include nsDialogs.nsh

Var MyPort
Var PortEdit

Function .onInit
StrCpy $MyPort "${DEFAULTPORT}"
FunctionEnd

Page Directory
Page Custom MyPageCreate MyPageLeave
Page InstFiles


Function MyPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0u 10% 20u 12u "Port: "
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateNumber} 20u 10% 40u 12u "$MyPort"
Pop $PortEdit

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $PortEdit $MyPort
FunctionEnd

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File "Sample.exe"

; Write the chosen port to a config file:
WriteIniStr "$InstDir\Config.ini" "Network" "Port" "$MyPort"
SectionEnd
```